# Spring interceptor not called after request dispatch

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, java-ee-6, spring-restcontroller

I have this spring interceptor with `preHandle` and `afterCompletion` methods:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        String identificationDemande = "";
        try {
            identificationDemande = new ObjectMapper().readTree(request.getInputStream()).path("test").asText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("JSON format unvalid", e);
            return true;
        }

        if (StringUtils.equals(identificationDemande, "1")) {
            log.info("preHandle Test without forward");
            return true;
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("newUrl");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        log.info("after completion test");
    }

}
```

When `identificationDemande==1` and my webservice call is not forwarded, then `aftercompletion` method is triggered. But when `identificationDemande!=1` and `dispatcher.forward(request, response)` is called, then `aftercompletion` is not triggered... I know that this seams to be logic, but is there anyway that I can intercept also these forwarded calls after their completion?

Answer (score 0):

- You already know in your `preHandle` when `dispatcher.forward(request, response)` returns. So you can do

```
      try {
         dispatcher.forward(request, response);
         //response is complete now
      }
      finally {
        //your logic
      }
      return false;
```

Comment: The interceptor is configured to intercept a path pattern which include the forwarded request! and how adding try bloc will resolve anything?!

Comment: I understood from your question, you wanted to do some cleanup task which you would have done normally in `afterCompletion` but since you are handling the response yourself, you do it immediately after in prehandle

Comment: No I don't want to do any cleanup, I just want the afterCompletion to be called